# Tensorflow: Custom TF Layer Is not JSON Serializable but have get_config() implemented

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, serialization

I have a built a custom layer for the purpose of rescaling data directly inside the model. This is necessary because I have a separate model that will be constructed from the linking of multiple models. Each of these models has its own scaling functions. When building the individual models I perform rescaling outside of the model, but once the layers are linked, this is no longer possible. As such, it must be implemented in the proposed manner.

I have created two sub-classed layers, `FeatureMinMaxScaler()` and `FeatureMinMaxDescaler()` (shown below), and I have implemented `get_config()` in both of them.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as krs
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sys import exit

(x,y),(xtest,ytest) = tf.keras.datasets.boston_housing.load_data()
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler2 = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(x)
transformed = scaler.transform(x)

class FeatureMinMaxScaler( krs.layers.Layer ):
    def __init__(self, max_data, min_data, limits = (0.,1.) ):
        super(FeatureMinMaxScaler, self).__init__(trainable=False)
        # max_data = max_data.astype('float32')
        # min_data = min_data.astype('float32')
        self.max_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(max_data,dtype='float64')
        self.min_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(min_data,dtype='float64')
        self.limits = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(limits),dtype='float64')
        self.range = tf.constant(limits[1]-limits[0],dtype='float64')

        self.inv_denominator = tf.divide(tf.constant(1.,dtype='float64'), tf.subtract(self.max_data,self.min_data) )
        self.inv_denominator = tf.where(tf.math.is_inf(self.inv_denominator),tf.constant(0.,dtype='float64'),self.inv_denominator)

        self.scaling_multiplier = tf.multiply(self.inv_denominator,self.range)
        self.range_min = tf.constant(limits[0],dtype='float64')
        self.num_outputs = max_data.size


    def build(self, input_shape):
        pass

    def call(self, input):

        return tf.cast(tf.add( tf.multiply( tf.subtract(tf.cast(input,dtype='float64'), self.min_data), self.scaling_multiplier ), self.range_min ),dtype='float32')

    def get_config(self):
        data = {    'max_data': self.max_data,
                    'min_data': self.min_data,
                    'limits': self.limits,
                    'range': self.range,
                    'inv_denominator': self.inv_denominator,
                    'scaling_multiplier': self.scaling_multiplier,
                    'range_min': self.range_min,
                    'num_outputs': self.num_outputs}
        return data

class FeatureMinMaxDescaler( krs.layers.Layer ):
    def __init__(self, max_data, min_data, limits = (0.,1.) ):
        super(FeatureMinMaxDescaler, self).__init__(trainable=False)
        # max_data = max_data.astype('float32')
        # min_data = min_data.astype('float32')
        self.max_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(max_data,dtype='float64')
        self.min_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(min_data,dtype='float64')
        self.limits = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(limits),dtype='float64')
        self.range = tf.constant(limits[1]-limits[0],dtype='float64')

        self.inv_denominator = tf.divide(tf.constant(1.,dtype='float64'), self.range)

        self.scaling_multiplier = tf.multiply(self.inv_denominator,tf.subtract(self.max_data,self.min_data))
        self.range_min = tf.constant(limits[0],dtype='float64')
        self.num_outputs = max_data.size


    def build(self, input_shape):
        pass

    def call(self, input):
        return tf.cast(tf.add( tf.multiply( tf.subtract(tf.cast(input,dtype='float64'), self.range_min), self.scaling_multiplier ), self.min_data ),dtype='float32')

    def get_config(self):
        data = {    'max_data': self.max_data,
                    'min_data': self.min_data,
                    'limits': self.limits,
                    'range': self.range,
                    'inv_denominator': self.inv_denominator,
                    'scaling_multiplier': self.scaling_multiplier,
                    'range_min': self.range_min,
                    'num_outputs': self.num_outputs}
        return data

inputs = krs.Input(shape=(x.shape[1],))
outputs = FeatureMinMaxScaler(scaler.data_max_, scaler.data_min_)(inputs)

model = krs.models.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = outputs )

model.compile(optimizer='adam')

krs.models.save_model(model,"./serialization_test.mdl")
```

However, when I try to save models that use these scaling layers I receive this error

```
TypeError: ('Not JSON Serializable:', <tf.Tensor: shape=(13,), dtype=float64, numpy=
array([ 88.9762, 100.    ,  27.74  ,   1.    ,   0.871 ,   8.725 ,
       100.    ,  10.7103,  24.    , 711.    ,  22.    , 396.9   ,
        37.97  ])>)
```

What is causing this problem? How do I fix it?

Comment: why are you converting everything to Tensor? It is not really necessary

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Is it not? I was doing it as standard practice because some of the other scaling functions would need to change after compile time. I can see where it isn't necessary here because a the featurewise minmax scaler doesn't need to change after initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow tensors are not json serializable. You need to only use primitive data types in the dict which is returned from get_config() method.

Also, you don't need to save all the member variable, only the values that are needed to recreate the Layer is enough. So in your case max_data, min_data, limits is sufficient. Also it looks like you don't need these to be tensors. So set these 3 variables as follows in your constructor.

```
        self.max_data = max_data
        self.min_data = min_data
        self.limits = limits
```

and in

```
    def get_config(self):
        data = {    'max_data': self.max_data,
                    'min_data': self.min_data,
                    'limits': self.limits}
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thank you! Part of the reason for saving all of the variables was to reduce how many calculations were necessary to be done every time that `call()` was executed. This is particularly important for division.

Comment: You can still retain those calculations in the constructors so the calculation is done only once when the layer is created. You don't need to have it in get_config since these are all derived from the 3 variables which are passed as input to the constructor.